# Customizing CRUD list.html in PlayFramework

Tags: java, crud, playframework

Hello 
I'm trying to customize the list.html view for the CRUD section of a play application.

My model is like this

I have an object with a relation to an other object like so:

```
@Entity
public class MyObjectA extends Model {

    @Required
    public String myObjectAName;

    ...

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public MyObjectB myObjectB;
}
```

Now in the list.html that I overwride I have this

```
<div id="crudListTable">
    #{crud.table fields:['myObjectB', 'myObjectAName'] /}
</div>
```

Now doing this code will display something like this when calling the following url http://myplayapp/admin/myObjectAs in a browser

myObjectB ***_*_** myObjectAName

MyObjectB[1] ***_*_** Hey this a name for myObjectAName
MyObjectB[2] ***_*_** Hey this is another name for myObjectAName

Note the use of the Object name and the object id in [] for my MyObjectB.

So to display the myObjectBName property of MyObjectB in the list above, I try this:

```
<div id="crudListTable">
    #{crud.table fields:['myObjectB.myObjectBName', 'myObjectAName'] /}
</div>
```

But then I get this error

> Execution error occured in template {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/table.html. >Exception raised was MissingPropertyException : No such property: myObjectB.myObjectBName >for class: models.MyObjectA.

Of course MyObjectB has a public property myObjectBName

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working, because The `fields` parameter just takes a list of field names of the class to display (here `MyObjectA`) and `"myObjectB.myObjectBName"` isn't the name of a field in `MyObjectA`.

There are two ways to do this:

The simple solution is to override the `toString()` method of `MyObjectB`. This has the disadvantage, that the same string is used everywere a `MyObjectB` is displayed, and that may be not what you want.

Example:

```
public class MyObjectB extends Model {

  // ...

  @Override
  public String toString(() {
    return this.myObjectBName;
  }

}
```

The list specifc solution is to use the [`crud.custom` tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/crud#custom).

Example:

```
#{crud.table fields:['myObjectB', 'myObjectAName']}
   #{crud.custom 'myObjectB'}
       ${object.myObjectB.myObjectBName}
   #{/crud.custom}
#{/crud.table}
```

Comment: Thank you RoToRa! The crud.custom tag is exactly what I needed